# Is dp based on the physical size of the screen? (dp =1/160 of an inch)

Tags: android

Is this definition correct?

*dp Density-independent Pixels - 1/160 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.*

I have found conflicting information:

The official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) assumes **scaled proportionally** in equation “px = dp * (dpi / 160)”.
Also [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhszwkcay2A)  (3:02) Roman Nurik says “**scaled proportionally**”

But in official documentation:

> px Pixels - corresponds to actual pixels on the screen. in Inches -
>   based on the physical size of the screen. mm Millimeters - based on
>   the physical size of the screen. pt Points - 1/72 of an inch based on
>   the physical size of the screen. dp Density-independent Pixels - An
>   abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen.
>   These units are relative to a 160 dpi (dots per inch) screen, on which
>   1dp is roughly equal to 1px. When running on a higher density screen,
>   the number of pixels used to draw 1dp is scaled up by a factor
>   appropriate for the screen's dpi. Likewise, when on a lower density
>   screen, the number of pixels used for 1dp is scaled down. The ratio of
>   dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, **but not necessarily
>   in direct proportion**.

If my definition is correct, Why introduce a new physical size measure if we already have the well-known mm, in and pt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A measurement unit like `mm` or `in` would be way less confusing since `dp` measures the same real world observed length. It would be misleading on the other hand since `dp` is not an absolutely defined unit.

The use of screen density buckets means that `dp` is a bit fuzzy - but it will stay within reasonable (+/-20% ?) accuracy. Real world displays are usually not exactly e.g. 160dpi they can be 173.4 dpi and still be classified as 160dpi. The math carried out to convert from `dp` to pixels on the screen is done based on these buckets and that means that the accuracy of `dp` depends on how accurately your device screen meets it's classification.

But to clear your doubt: 160dp is always 1 (fuzzy) inch regardless of what device you hold in your hand. Easier to think of: 50dp = 1 (small) finger wide.

---

`px Pixels` on the other hand are actual pixels. A full HD display has 1920x1080 of them but that unit says nothing about the screen size or how big such a pixel will appear to the user. `dp` or `dip` is a different unit and should have never been called "pixel" in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this out after 20:00

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBKGbCu0pJg&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF

Join Nick Butcher, Adam Koch and Roman Nurik discussing all about Android Units of measure.